# color: none effect in CSS to prevent override

Tags: css

**Update (problem):** Once application is pushed to dev server, asp includes inject styles that override the actual custom coded needed styles. One instance below, wrapper div with a tag overrides all styled `<a>` tags and links within. It would be really quick to use `none !important` on the CSS color module. As disabling that everything resolves correctly. Now, I can do this with jQuery or (can move all a tag classes to the `<head>` with `!important` and override. Just wondering any thoughts or hacks about using or getting a '`none`' effect in this type of scenario, that is all.

---

Let's just say situation / environment out of your hands.

And you must override a style.

Say your trying to override a color assigned to a div. Is the below valid / will it work? Is there an alternative. *Defining a color not a possibility as will override other `<a>` tag colors.*

```
#HUGEwrapperdiv a { 
   color: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Once `!important` comes into play you are basically defeating on of the most important characteristics of CSS - cascades.

Comment: Your edit makes the question more vague. Colors can't be `none`. So what exactly do you mean if you say `color:none`? What should the `a` elements look like? Can you make a mockup screenshot of the desired result?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it won't work. It will be ignored because `none` is an invalid value for the [`color` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/).

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could set it to `transparent`/`inherit`/`initial`.

These values are somewhat self-explanatory. The [value `inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) will cause the element to inherit the computed value of the `color` property from its parent element. The [value `initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) will set the `color` to the browser's default color (likely specified in the user agent stylesheet). It's worth pointing out that the `initial` value [isn't fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) in all browsers.

Comment: `currentcolor` will also work and will have the same effect as `inherit`.

Comment: Thanks, essentially none of these worked for me. And ultimately I guess you cannot achieve a 'none' or '0'.

Comment: @YourConscious is that a question about CSS specificity rather than the color thing?

Comment: @YourConscious I saw the updates in the question but couldn't really get it, just to say that it is possible to override !important if you want. I also don't understand, what you do expect for color:none to work?

Comment: @Pangloss It's not possible to achieve what the OP is trying to do in plain CSS, though.

Comment: @JoshCrozier OK, it's just very confusing, everything has to have a color, either transparent or any color, it's not like a border i.e. with border, without border either one is totally fine, but what is color:none?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, as it seems to me that you're trying to get font to have no color/be transparent, that if you set the CSS color property (color:) to rgba(0,0,0,0), it will set the text to black, but also set its opacity to 0 so it won't be seen. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

to prevent overide you also can use in styles or make a custom class

```
color: unset !important
```